# Blazor webassembly: canvas.toDataUrl()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet, blazor

Using Blazor WebAssembly (3.2.0 preview 5) with [BlazorLeaflet](https://github.com/Mehigh17/BlazorLeaflet) to show a map. On this map I want to put an imageOverlay that I want to be able to update more or less often (sometimes not at all and sometimes up to about 1-2 times per second). With a normal js this was quite easily done with the following code snippet (together with [Leaflet.Overlay.Rotated](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated) plugin) :
Initially:

```
var map = L.map('mapElement', {
        crs: crs,
        continuousWorld: true,
        center: latlong, // Set center location
        zoom: 9, // Set zoom level
        minzoom: 0,
        maxzoom: 13
    });
var overlay = L.imageOverlay.rotated(imageurl, point1, point2, point3, {
    opacity: 0.4,
    interactive: true,
    attribution: "MyUpdatingImage"
}); 
map.addLayer(overlay);
```

Then updating the image is simply done by:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
//..
// Populating imageData.data with values for r,g,b,a (0-255)
//..
overlay.setUrl(canvas.toDataURL());
```

I have briefly tested this [Blazor Canvas](https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Canvas) plugin but unfortunately there is no **toDataURL()** equivalent method/function as far as I can see..
Is there anyone who knows of an alternative method in Blazor WebAssembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do this, just use the `IJSRuntime` service to call a JavaScript method from Blazor WASM and make the update. Example:

```html
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<canvas id="myMap"></canvas>
```

```cs
@code {
    private async Task RefreshMap(){
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myJsMethod", "myNewMapData"); // send any data required
    }
}
```